# How to make android edit text uneditable when switch is off?

Tags: java, android

I am brand new to android development and I am having difficulties trying to make my editText uneditable after a switch is set to off. The problem is that The switch function doesn't work. Even after it is set to off, I can still edit the text.
here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        final View switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.editSwitch);
        final EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bioTxt);
        switch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (switch1.getContext().toString().equals("On")) {

                    mEdit.setEnabled(true);
                }

                else if (switch1.getContext().toString().equals("Off")) {

                    EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bioTxt);
                    mEdit.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

    };
}
```

Comment: What does/doesn't work here?

Comment: The switch function doesn't work. Even after it is set to off, I can still edit the text..

Comment: remove the EditText line in the else statement.

Comment: Would I place that on the outside, before the switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Switch` has a function `isChecked()` which returns true if the Switch is in the 'On' position. Therefore your onClick method can just be:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mEdit.setEnabled(switch1.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: @user2206030 - Make sure the type of switch1 is `Switch`, rather than `View`.

Comment: I am using a Relative Layout, with Text View and the switch xml is : <Switch android:id="@+id/editSwitch" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/Webstietxt" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Edit Mode" /> –

Comment: @user2206030 - yes, the XML is fine. It is your declaration of `switch1` in your code (that is currently `final View switch1`) that should be changed to `final Switch switch1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch1.getContext().toString()
```

What are you trying to do here?  getContext on a view returns the activity that owns it.  It does not return anything that will turn into "On" or "Off".  You need to call some other function.  I'm not sure which, as it looks like its a custom view.

Comment: I have a view with text edits and I want to disable the ability to type in thoese text edits when the switch is set to off.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what type of View your switch is and what functions it has.  What I do know is that you definiely don't want to call getContext there.

Comment: I am using a Relative Layout, with Text View and the switch code is : <Switch
      android:id="@+id/editSwitch"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Webstietxt"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Edit Mode" />

Comment: Ah, didn't know there was a Switch class.  Try:   Switch switch = (Switch) v;  boolean checked = switch.isChecked();    That will tell you if its checked or not (on or off, basically).

Comment: if(checked == true){mEdit.setEnabled(true);}else if(checked == false){mEdit.setEnabled(false);} I did this, but its still the same result..